# Http URL connection can't read completely

Tags: android

I am facing with problem related Http Connection. 
MY code :

```
URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL(_url);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
}

if (url != null) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    try {
        urlConn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConn.setConnectTimeout(45000);

        if(response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            StringBuffer readData = new StringBuffer("");
            int size = 1024;
            char[] buffer = new char[size];
            int len;
            isr = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
            while ((len = isr.read(buffer, 0, size)) > 0) {
                readData.append(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        }
    } 
    catch(Exception e) {
    } 
    finally {
        if(urlConn != null) {

        try {
            urlConn.disconnect();
        } catch(Exception e) {            
        }
    }
    if(isr != null) {
        try {
           isr.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {                
        }            
    }
}
```

This code can't download data completely.
For example :
Total size to read       : 13901 bytes 
Above code can read size : 12937 bytes

What is wrong here ?

Please advice guys.

Comment: How do you know it is 13901 bytes?  Is this in the HTTP content-length header or are you looking at the file you're serving on disk?

Comment: Documentation says that -1 is returned when you get to the end of the stream, not 0. Even with that fix I assume that Ramp's reply is probably the reason why you're having issues.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read%28char[],%20int,%20int%29

Comment: Well, InputStream is not allowed to return 0 if at least 1 byte is requested, so checking for 'if (count > 0)' is actually ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked your code and it seems to be OK. But you have to bear in mind that you are reading chars (2 bytes type) - so your readData.length() will show number of characters, not bytes. I made a test and changed your InputStreamReader to BufferedInputStream and type of buffer to byte[]. The code read exactly the number of bytes I expected.
Regads!

Comment: While the underlying point about character conversion is valid, your comment on character taking 2 bytes is not generally correct -- only UTF-16/UCS-2 has fixed 2-bytes-per-char encoding, and they are not commonly used by web servers. UTF-8 is a variable length encoding (1 - 3 bytes per Java char); Latin-1 is fixed 1-byte per char and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Also to add to the accepted answer: I would consider code buggy because it does not specify what character encoding InputStreamReader is to use -- it's the platform default, which may different from what the resource is using. So always either specify encoding to use explicitly ("UTF-8"), or use a library that does this.